# Why does git delete ignored files under `directory/*` but not under `directory/`

Tags: git

As mentioned in [this post](http://blog.icefusion.co.uk/git-stash-can-delete-ignored-files-git-stash-u/)

> To put it another way, if you have the following in your .gitignore:

```
/my-ignored-directory/*
```

> Then you’re screwed – after a git stash save -u, my-ignored-file.txt
>   will be gone (and sorry, it’s not in the stash you just created
>   either).  Break out the undelete packages and hope for the best. 
>   Alternatively, if you have the following in your .gitignore:

```
/my-ignored-directory
```

> Then you’re golden – no worries, kick back, relax, my-ignored-file.txt
>   will stay exactly where it was prior to the git stash save -u.

Why is this difference? I'm also wondering if no files will be deleted if in my `.gitignore` file I have `/my-ignored-directory/` (with trailing slash)?

Comment: I just tested with my git version (1.9.1) and I lose the files in every case.

Comment: @werkritter, interesting, thanks for testing, I wish someone clarified the issue

Comment: @werkritter, how did you test? Can you please share the steps and the information? I just tried to run experiments and git didn't delete any file from ignored directory, however it deleted ignored files not in root directory.

Comment: @werkritter, I'm using 2.6.3 git version

Comment: I tried out 3 scenarios: in every case I created `ignored-dir` directory and put some files in there. Afterwards I modified `.gitignore`, adding `/ignored-dir` in the first scenario, `/ignored-dir/` in the second one, `/ignored-dir/*` in the third one. I added `.gitignore` to the index (`git add .gitignored`) and ran `git stash --keep-index --include-untracked`). That index related stuff was done in order to not stash `.gitignore` itself. In every case I lost `ignored-dir` along with its contents.

Comment: thanks, how did you manage to create a folder with the name `/ignored-dir`? The slash is not allowed in a filename

Comment: I didn't — why do you think I had? `/ignored-dir` was just an entry in `.gitignore`. Leading slash is a part of `.gitignore` syntax — see `gitignore (5)` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Results of both you examples will be the same, ignored files are gone. There is of course solution for it described in documentation:

> If the --include-untracked option is used, all untracked files are also stashed and then cleaned up with git clean, leaving the working directory in a very clean state. **If the --all option is used instead then the ignored files are stashed and cleaned in addition to the untracked files.**

Git internally calls [git clean -d](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f5b6079871904ba5b0a8548f91545f126caf898b/git-stash.sh#L277) to put *working directory in a very clean state*.

Command that you want is:

```
git stash --include-untracked --all
```

Comment: can you please explain than why files are gone in both cases?

Comment: thanks, is `git clean -d` called only for `git stash --include-untracked` option? Can you please share a link to the resource stating that?

Comment: It's mentioned in documentation just for option `--include-untracked`. See `git stash --help`.

Comment: thanks, but it states that it runs `git clean`, the `-d` option is not mentioned anywhere

Comment: FYI https://github.com/git/git/blob/f5b6079871904ba5b0a8548f91545f126caf898b/git-stash.sh#L277, but there is quite a lot logic around, didn't track it more further.

Comment: thanks, I just tested it with my git version 2.6.3 and files in ignored directories are not deleted, but ignored files in root directory are deleted. It seems that `git clean` is executed without `d` option, but the source code you pointed at indicates the opposite... confusing...