# after git stash -u and git stash pop, some ignored&untracked file are missing

Tags: git

I encountered the above problem, for convenience, I will use a small example to recreate the scene

```
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/nick/Desktop/bugtest/.git/
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ echo original > file1.txt
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ mkdir data
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ echo datafile2 > data/file2.txt
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    data/
    file1.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ git add .
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ git commit -m "init commit"
[master (root-commit) 28ce869] init commit
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 data/file2.txt
 create mode 100644 file1.txt
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ echo datafile3 > data/file3.txt
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ echo /data/* > .gitignore
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ cat .gitignore 
/data/*
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitignore

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ echo datafile4 > data/file4.txt
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitignore

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ git rm -r --cached data/
rm 'data/file2.txt'
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    data/file2.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitignore


nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ git add .
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ git commit -m "rm data, upload gitignore"
[master 399dd82] rm data, upload gitignore
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 delete mode 100644 data/file2.txt
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ echo change > file1.txt
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file1.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ ll
./
../
data/
file1.txt
.git/
.gitignore
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ git stash -u
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 399dd82 rm data, upload gitignore
HEAD is now at 399dd82 rm data, upload gitignore
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ ll
./
../
file1.txt
.git/
.gitignore
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ git stash pop
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file1.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (acb5e64200a875485799cb942c3898e1791abc5b)
nick@nick-linux:~/Desktop/bugtest$ ll
./
../
file1.txt
.git/
.gitignore
```

You can see that at the end the data folder disappears.I want to know how it works, and how can I recover my lost folder. Thank you!

My working configuration is "git version 2.7.4; ubuntu 16.04LTS".

---

The above is an example, here I present my actual operation in the project. It may be helpful to find the missing folder.

I wanted to create a branch locally to provide development productivity, so I read the documentation for Git Branch and Git Stash, but I had trouble actually doing it.
I've been working on the master branch, and there are some changes that haven't been committed yet, so

```
git stash --keep-index -u
git stash apply
git stash -u
git checkout -b newbranch
git stash pop
git stash drop stash@{0}
```

After working on the new branch for a few hours, I suddenly realized that I had lost several folders that had previously been untracked on the master branch and marked in .gitignore. In addition, I also found that some untracked folders were not lost, and they were also marked in .gitignore.

I didn't notice when these folders were lost, after git stash -u or after git checkout -b ?
I switched back to the matser branch

```
git stash -u
git checkout master
```

and these folders are still missing.

After research, I reproduced the above simple example, and guessed that this is the reason for the loss.

Comment: That looks like a bug in `git stash`, complete with a reproducer. What Git version are you running? You might want to report this to [the Git mailing list](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#git).

Comment: Meanwhile: I recommend avoiding `git stash`. It's had bugs of this sort before. In particular `git stash -u` makes a three-commit stash. The third commit holds the untracked files. Git immediately removes these untracked files after making this third commit. It looks like Git removed some files that *didn't* get into the third commit, so that they were not restored by `git stash pop`, and if that is the case, they are not retrievable through Git. You might be able to use an OS-provided recovery system such as MacOS's "time machine".

Comment: @torek Thankyou, my working configuration is "git version 2.7.4; ubuntu 16.04LTS". In the git documentation, git stash -u is introduced like this: "All untracked files are also stashed and then cleaned up with git clean." However, by default, git clean will only remove untracked files that have not been ignored. So I am confused why some of ignored&untracked file is missing.(not all ignored&untracked file are lost, i guess the difference may lie in whether git rm -r --cached is used)

Comment: Right - that's the difference between `-a`, which stores all files even if `.gitignore`-ed, and `-u`, which doesn't. The set of files to remove is *supposed* to be the set of files stored in this third commit. I don't recall such a bug in 2.7.4. I do know there was a bug introduced when `git stash push` was added, but that was about 2.13.0 or so.

Comment: @torek I found [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635044/why-does-git-delete-ignored-files-under-directory-but-not-under-directory), which fits my situation,
this is my content of .gitignore
```
/data/*

/externel_data/*

/log/*

/example/
```
I found that folder `/log` and `/externel_data`  are missing, but the folder `/example` and 
`/data` is still there.

Comment: @torek The reason why `/data` is not lost may be because before I added it to gitignore, I uploaded this folder and related files inside to the remote, and did not `rm` it from the remote afterwards. 
So before I used git stash, there were some tracked files and also some untracked&ignored files in `/data` folder. 
At present, I don't quite understand how `git stash` performs clean work, so that untracked&ignored files in `/data` folder were not deleted like `/log`

Comment: Listing a file in `.gitignore` does not cause it to be untracked or ignored. Untracked-ness is a property of whether the given file is in Git's index. The index, however, is a temporary data structure: it's filled in from a commit, and then you add files to it with `git add`, or remove them from it with `git rm`. Switching to another commit switches the files that are in the (temporary) index. Committing saves the index as a snapshot. `git stash -u` makes three commits: one holds the index, one holds your work-tree, and the last holds your untracked files.

Comment: `git stash pop` somehow dropped my untracked files and lost like a week or two of work. I just spent that last few hours trying to recover my changes. Tried this: [link](https://mobilejazz.com/blog/how-to-recover-a-deleted-git-stash/) and that got me close but I think my deleting a branch made git lose those changes for good. Finally was able to recover the entire repo before I lost the changes thanks to macOS' Time Machine feature. @torek, thank you so much for mentioning "Time Machine." By the time I would have remembered this feature, that snapshot would have probably been deleted.

Comment: @arkane: there has been a bunch of recent work on `git stash` (follow-ons to the conversion to C code, breakages introduced by sparse checkout, fixes for those, breakages introduced by the fixes, etc.) and at this point I wouldn't run `git stash` in any repository of value myself.  If you can reproduce the bug, though, report it to the Git mailing list: they need more test cases in the Git test suite.